# minmax CSS function is not recognized in React project

Tags: css, reactjs, referenceerror, minmax

I used the following line to style a material UI grid in my react project.

**gridTemplateColumns: Repeat("auto-fit", **minmax**("300px", "1fr"))**

I get this error "ReferenceError: minmax is not defined".

It looks React knows the repeat CSS function but not the **minmax**  function.
I could not figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're currently trying to call functions and pass strings into them, but that's incorrect. `gridTemplateColumns` needs to be a string, not a function call. The string happens to look like function calls, but if any code needs to be run, the browser will do that, not you.

```
style={{
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))"
}}
```

Comment: You are right. That is what I should do when styling an element using inline styling. How would I do it if I were styling a material UI component? I am trying to apply the style to a material UI Grid component.